# Keyboard shortcuts with (eg. by Shift/Alt Gr) hidden keys

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

We have a lot of different keyboard layouts for big/small devices & languages.
Some shortcuts like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> may not work as the <kbd>=</kbd> key is hidden behind another key, in my case <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>. My **expectation** is that I can use the shortcut with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>, but this does not work.

This issue drives me mad and I cannot find relevant information online.

Remapping to a different shortcut is no option.

Comment: This can change by app. Sometimes, you need to press the keys *in the same position* as they are on an English keyboard; sometimes you need to generate the same *final character*. e.g for `alt =` try alt + the second key right of 0 [zero].

Comment: I took a look at the keymap and pressed the according button, but sadly this does not work